# Android, как поставить 2 анимации на одну кнопку

Tags: android, android-animation

У меня есть одна кнопка и одна картинка, я написал 2 анимации. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку анимации чередовались, но я не пойму как сделать так чтобы они запускались по очереди.

Код

```
        final RotateAnimation rotate1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 90, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate1.setDuration(300); rotate1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        final RotateAnimation rotate2 = new RotateAnimation(90, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate2.setDuration(300); rotate2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать через таймер. Когда вы включаете первую анимацию, то вместе с ней включайте и таймер который равен продолжительности анимации(300мс) и когда проходит время то делаете тоже самое со второй анимацией в методе таймера OnFinish(). Если надо то зациклите это всё